# Coloring figures of isoceles right triangles

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Are figures of isosceles right triangles known to be 3-colorable?

I'm considering the graphs induced by figures of finitely many non-overlapping (no common interior points) isosceles right triangles of the Euclidean plane; two triangles are connected when they have infinitely many points in common (i.e., no connections by the corners) : Are those graphs 3-colorable?

I'm also interested in the variant where in each triangle, the sides adjacent to the right angle are horizontal and vertical (in other words, the hypotenuse is NOT horizontal or vertical).